# How can Airflow be configured to use Snowflake as a backend?

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to configure Apache Airflow to use Snowflake as a backend database.  In theory it should work out of the box as it uses SQLAlchemy as a ORM, which supports Snowflake.

I have confirmed that SqlAlchemy works with Snowflake by successfully connecting to our Snowflake account.

I have installed Airflow using the alldb options using
`sudo pip install apache-airflow[alldbs]` and in the airflow.cfg file I have set the sql_alchemy_conn setting to a SqlAlchemy connection string that works in a manual test of SqlAlchemy's create_engine() call.

I am getting the following error message when running `airflow initdb`

````
[2019-06-20 14:08:28,268] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
DB: snowflake://MYUSER:***@myaccount.us-east-1/MYDATABASE/AIRFLOW?warehouse=LOAD_WH
[2019-06-20 14:08:28,756] {db.py:350} INFO - Creating tables
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 1096, in initdb
    db.initdb(settings.RBAC)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 91, in initdb
    upgradedb()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 358, in upgradedb
    command.upgrade(config, 'heads')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic/command.py", line 254, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 427, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 81, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 141, in load_module_py
    mod = imp.load_source(module_id, path, fp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 92, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 82, in run_migrations_online
    compare_type=COMPARE_TYPE,
  File "<string>", line 8, in configure
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 812, in configure
    opts=opts
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 172, in configure
    return MigrationContext(dialect, connection, opts, environment_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 111, in __init__
    self.impl = ddl.DefaultImpl.get_by_dialect(dialect)(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 65, in get_by_dialect
    return _impls[dialect.name]
KeyError: 'snowflake'```
````

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want, running Airflow's backend database on Snowflake? I don't think the latency Snowflake offers is sufficient to run Airflow smoothly. I think it's more typical to run Airflow on something like mysql/sqlite/postgres (https://airflow.apache.org/howto/initialize-database.html), then use Airflow to execute Snowflake queries.

Comment: Personally I would prefer using a local db for just this,  but our organization is pretty tight with EC2s as we require a security appliance to be running on each one.  I was hoping this way we can run this in a container and still be able to maintain state between runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I fixed adding this code to `env.py` so alembic could recognize Snowflake driver

```
from alembic.ddl.impl import DefaultImpl

class SnowflakeImpl(DefaultImpl):
    __dialect__ = 'snowflake'
```

Refs: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#alembic-support

Comment: How did you get around Airflow wanting to create a table in the meta db using indexes (which isn't supported in snowflake)?

Comment: Oh sorry, in my case was fixing Superset to use Snowflake as backend. Found this question diggiing into my own issues and I thinks airflow and superset uses same approach and libraries. Finally I gave up after many other considerations.